# How to reload Homestead projects after a new one was added to Homestead.yaml, without wiping out the database?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Stop me if you heard this one before.

I'm running Laravel on Homestead. During the past year I needed to add some new projects to my `Homestead.yaml`. Each time I set up a new project, I ran the command to "refresh" Homestead environment:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

The command **always** wipes my DB out. The tables are gone and I need to set up the DB all over again - a few SQL dumps and migrations.

Now, according to this **[thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-proper-way-to-refresh-homestead-after-making-changes-to-the-homesteadyaml-file?page=1)** on Laracast, about the `reload` command:

> It will restart your homestead machine and apply the changes you made,
>   while keeping your database data intact.

Obviously, that's not true in my case (and in case of my peer developers). Could be it's not true to the entire universe.

Is there a reliable way to reload projects in Homestead **without** dropping all the tables from my database?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the database dropping has been removed from Homestead in a **[commit](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/commit/f2931d94d9598c330925e3ceb45fccd50c66bcae)** tagged with `v3.0.2`.

I'm using Homestead `v0.2.7`, so for all who want to get rid of the DB dropping, just find the files changed by the commit and apply the same changes. The files are:

- `[homestead-directory]/scripts/create-mysql.sh`
- `[homestead-directory]/scripts/create-postgres.sh`

The second one applies only to those using PostgreSQL.

Cheers.